# Test existance of directory in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, execution, mkdir, spock

I have directory in which I have to put some results, but the user can configure it
If the directory does not exist I have to create it. But now I have to write test for that code.

**getOutputPath()** is getter method

```
@Optional
def outputPath = new File('build/sampleDir')


@TaskAction
def generate() {
    if (!getOutputPath().exists()) {
        project.mkdir(getOutputPath())
    }
```

The creation is in the Action closure so this is executed in the execution phase, but if I try:

```
    ...
    def 'change default outputPath dir'() {
    when:
    someTask.outputPath = new File(project.rootProject.buildDir, "newPath")
    then:
    ....

    expect:
    project.afterEvaluate {
        generateQRFromTextTask.getOutputQRPath().exists() == true
    }
}
```

For my surprise this code pass as well the same but with   **project.gradle.buildFinished {**.
Without them it fails. Why the test passes with **afterEvaluate** ?

And what is the best way to make this checks(for directory existing? In *constructor* or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property should be annotated with `@OutputDirectory`, in which case the directory will be created automatically.

PS: Depending on the exact nature of your test, `afterEvaluate` may never be triggered.

PPS: A property that has a default value doesn't need to be annotated with `@Optional`.

Comment: Thanks, Peter for the answer and for the advises .